# PHP to upload Facebook Photos

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use Facebook Graph API to upload a photo to a Facebook Fan page, I was able to upload the photo but it is uploaded as a small thumbnail with my hostname written beside it twice (i.e. www.myhost.comwww.myhost.com)

I need to upload the photo with its original size without anything written beside it

I'm using:

```
$params = array(
   "access_token" => $access_token,
   "picture" => "http://www.myhost.com/fb/Azkar-001.png",
);
$ret = $fb->api('/myID/feed', 'POST', $params);
```

Appreciate your feedback as I'm new with the graph API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Adam, HYG the full code:

```
<?php
require_once("facebook.php");

$access_token = "Add_Your_Access_Token_here";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
   'appId'  => 'Add_Your_App_ID_Here',
   'secret' => 'Add_Your_App_Secret_Here',
   'fileUpload' => true, // I put this as False in my original program and this was the reason for my early issues
   'cookie' => true // enable optional cookie support
));

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);

$file = "@".realpath("001.png"); //Put the file path here

$args = array(
   "message" => "Photo Caption'"
   "access_token" => $access_token,
   "image" => $file
);

$data = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'post', $args); //This is the line that made everything working fine, thanks to Adam

if ($data) print_r("success");

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

A common mistake is using `me/feed`, `me/feed` targets and publish status updates & link posts to the user's stream

To upload a photo to the user stream/timeline use `me/photos`

```
$ret = $fb->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $params);
```

wait, you still have another problem, which's using the param `picture`, why? 
because you're uploading from a URL, replace `picture` with `url`

```
$params = array(
   "access_token" => $access_token,
   "url" => "http://www.myhost.com/fb/Azkar-001.png",
);
$ret = $fb->api('/me/photos', 'POST', $params);
```

Comment: Adam, when I used the code that I wrote below, whenever I use it to upload a new photo the whole album appears with all the photos in the timeline, is there a way so that whenever I upload a new photo it appears on its own post, also do you know how I can upload all the photos into the album (manually) and then use the graph API so that they appear as posts on the timeline each on its own post?